# Maple: Find intersection of two functions

Tags: intersection, maple

I have a Maple worksheet like this:

[image]

And have been unable to figure out how to find the intersection of the two, as fsolve returns an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that **f** is a function and **g** is an equation. And you want to solve **f(x)=y**, not **f(x)=0**. So your **fsolve** command should be

```
fsolve({f(x)=y, g}, {x,y}, x= -2..-1);
```

By changing the x-range, you can get all three intersection points this way. There is no need to give a y-range.